# How to pass a selected ToolStripMenItem item name into another method with dynamically built menu and menu items

Tags: c#

Using: Visual Studio 2015 Community, C# .NET 4.5.2, Windows 10

I have researched many topics on this however, I cannot seem to find a solution that solves what I am trying to attempt and I am struggling to find the answer I am looking for. I am relatively new to C# and new to working with menus so I am still learning.

*** BACKGROUND ***

Ultimately what I want to do is add menus and menu items at runtime from data stored in a database to an existing menu attached to a panel. The data will come from the database because the menu items will be different based on which user is logged in. For now I just created a simple menu for testing which is not driven by database information.

I think I have a good handle on creating the menu and menu items from a database source so I do not need help with that, what I need help with is passing the selected menu item to another method in order to perform the necessary function the menu item calls for. I have included my code example below.

For testing, and so I can get a handle on working with menus, I created a simple menu and added menu items at runtime and not from the database at this point, this is just a test.

*** CORE QUESTION ***

I have a MenuStrip called “MainMenu” attached to a panel in Form1. Ultimately the menu will be in a panel so that is why I set it up like this.

The menu and menu items all show up fine, so that all works as expected, the problem is when I click on a menu item under a menu, MainMenuSub.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItemClicked); is called and it will take me to the MenuItemClicked  method as expected and I get the MessageBox, but only on the first menu item.

For example if I select “1st Menu, Menu Item 1”, under 1st Menu, I get the MessageBox, but if I select “1st Menu, Menu Item 2” I get nothing. None of the other menu items will go into the method and bring up the MessageBox either.

I was expecting to get the MessageBox for each and every menu item I selected regardless of which menu item I selected and regardless of which menu I was under.

My question is why does it only work for the first menu item and not all the others?

Ideally, I would like to have the MessageBox display the menu that was selected, as well as the menu item that was selected below it, as this information will be necessary to apply the proper function based on what which item was selected and which menu it was selected from.

Any help, ideas, or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem NewMenuItem = new MenuItem();

        this.MainMenu.Items.Add("1st Menu");
        this.MainMenu.Items.Add("2nd Menu");
        this.MainMenu.Items.Add("3rd Menu");
        this.MainMenu.Items.Add("4th Menu");

        ToolStripMenuItem MainMenuSub = (ToolStripMenuItem)

        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[0]).DropDownItems.Add("1st Menu, Menu Item 1");
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[0]).DropDownItems.Add("1st Menu, Menu Item 2");

        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[1]).DropDownItems.Add("2nd Menu, Menu Item 1");
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[1]).DropDownItems.Add("2nd Menu, Menu Item 2");

        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[2]).DropDownItems.Add("3rd Menu, Menu Item 1");
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[2]).DropDownItems.Add("3rd Menu, Menu Item 2");

        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[3]).DropDownItems.Add("4th Menu, Menu Item 1");
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)MainMenu.Items[3]).DropDownItems.Add("4th Menu, Menu Item 2");

        MainMenuSub.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItemClicked);
    }

    void MenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripItem MenuItem = (ToolStripItem)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Menu: " + MenuItem.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing something on this line: `ToolStripMenuItem MainMenuSub = (ToolStripMenuItem)` ?

Comment: Good question I am not sure. I guess I thought that MainMenuSub.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItemClicked); would cover all menu items in MainMenuSub and pass the menu item through the event handler regardless of which menu item was selected, but obviously not.

Comment: That's right - you'd need to attach an event handler for each item. You can use the same handler/method, and distinguish between them within the handler.

Comment: My question was - what object are you casting as `ToolStripMenuItem` and assigning to `MainMenuSub` ?

Comment: First and foremost, than you for taking the time to help me. I think I get what you are saying and I have come across what you are saying in my research, whereas I would create a method for each item, I think that is what you are getting at. However, I will be building this menu dynamically from a database, so how would I attach an event handler for each item under that condition? It will never be known how many menu items there will be at any given time for a given menu. If my menu was static it would probably be pretty cut and dry. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I am trying to assign menu items for each menu under MainMenuSub if that helps.

Comment: When you create an item dynamically, attach it to the **same** event handler. So, irrespective of which dynamically created item is clicked, it is the same event handler that is called. In the event handler, determine which is the actual item that was clicked by examining the sender. This way, you don't have to create multiple event handlers (which is impossible at compile time, given your menu items are built at runtime).

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757574/dynamically-adding-toolstripmenuitems-to-a-menustrip-c-winforms and take a look at the topmost answer which does the same time for a ToolStrip. The idea is the same, and you can see how the event handler assigned to the click within the loop is the same event handler.

Comment: I will look at the example you provided. Thank you for your help on this,

Comment: I came across this post before, in my research, I couldn't get it to work, I will try it again. Maybe I missed something.